# PHP: I can't have users logged into site on multiple browsers

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication

Apologies if this question is already posted.  I didn't find the answer i was looking for when searching through the related questions.

I have a login system I've just created that works with Facebook. Once the user logs in with their Facebook info and then I create profile in my database for them. I start a session upon successful login and store the user's id in that session. This setup so far has worked fine, but I've recently noticed if I try to login to the site on another browser (1xChrome, 1xIE, so on...) at the same time it wont let me.  How can I fix this problem?  I would like the user to be able to not only log into multiple browsers on the same computer at the same time, but if they stay logged in at home be able to still log in from another computer.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Yes I'm interested in allowing user's to log into multiple browsers as in 1xChrome, 1xIE, 1xSafari, etc.  I should've been more clear. sorry.

Comment: Are you creating the session USING the user's id?  If so, that rings a warning bell, but it's probably not the cause of your problem.

Comment: Well I was storing the facebook id in the database but the primary key id that is auto-incremented was the one I was using. I'd do a session_start() and then create a $_SESSION['userid'] and store the user's id in it.  Not sure if this is the correct way, if not please explain as I've only done this because I'm very new to it.

Comment: That seems fine.  I was worried you were NAMING the session with their id.  Like `session_name($id); session_start();` Very bad idea.  But storing it in the session seems fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to do some more research into cookies.

Your users should not be able to use multiple instances of the same browser (for example, 4 Internet Explorer windows) to log in.

Your users SHOULD be able to use different browsers (ie 1 x IE, 1 x Firefox, 1 x Chrome or any of the above browsers + 1 with Private Browsing/Incognito/etc enabled).

The reason for this is because the cookie storage is different.  You could technically use different Firefox profiles, too, I think...

... but to get back to your question - you might want to learn more about Cookies and their function in sessions.

Answer (score 1):

The session should not be terminated, unless you do a check and terminate it yourself. An issue could be the actual facebook login. If facebook does not allow multiple logins(i think it does not), your first browser session will be getting an expired session( if you check on the facebook login status ), and this could cause your script to refresh the state of the first client (again, if you handle it like that).

Comment: Is facebook's oauth that much different from Google's? I know i can log in on multiple different browsers on stackoverflow using my google id